# Measurable projection theorem 

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Hi ;

i have this theorem from the book :Set-valued analysis

> Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a
>   complete $\sigma$-finite measure space
>   , $X$ a complete separable metric
>   space and $G\in\mathcal{A}\times
> > \mathcal{B}(X)$ . Then it's projection
>   $pr_{\Omega}(G)=\lbrace t\in \Omega
> > ,\exists x\in X, (t,x)\in G\rbrace \in
> > \mathcal{A} $

there is a prove of this in the book of Castaing "convexe and measurable multifunction"
in chapter 3
but i dont understand it

please help me

Thank you .

Comment: Well there is the obvious advice: Try another book! Also: This is not the kind of question that is appropriate for MathOverflow. Consider asking it on other sites like math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: how i must ask it ? please 

Comment: have you another book ?


Comment: A tangential side-note.  We see questions from time to time asking why we care if a measure space is complete.  Here is one example: this projection result fails in general with an incomplete measure.

Comment: About half a year ago I scribbled in my notebooks that the measurable projection theorem can be found in the fourth volume of Fremlin's books. http://www.essex.ac.uk/maths/people/fremlin/mt.htm But unfortunately I didn't write down the page number. If you just google the phrase "measurable projection theorem" you will also find a wealth of information. 

Comment: @Gerald Edgar: when the measur space is not complete they say that the projection is universaly measurable 
@Willie Wrong : i don't find it